# JavaScript qual Api é essa?

Tags: javascript, api, javascript-eventos

Poderiam me dar uma direção a respeito do menu lateral "Bolinhas" onde troca as paginas por ela? Teria um Api, para isso? E na parte da bicicleta existe alguns pontos com sinal de + , onde usuário passa o mouse e exibe uma informação, o que seria isso?

**Exemplo:** http://themenectar.com/demo/salient-product/#features

Qual biblioteca JavaScript é responsável pelo contextualização e sequencia de imagens ?  Para trabalhar com ela de tal forma que vai dar a sensação de 3D porém não passa se uma sequencia de imagem

Comment: Isso é Parallax

Comment: A questão da Bike, você faz com CSS e JS puro

Comment: A maioria do que tem ali da para resolver só com CSS. Mas a sua pergunta é ampla demais! Concentre sua pergunta em algo mais específico, e coloque o código que já tem pronto, mesmo que tenha que fazer mais de uma pergunta! Da forma que está fica não da para  te responder direito

Comment: Se você inspecionar a página verá que as bibliotecas usadas são JQuery, Jquery.UI e MediaElement para o player do vídeo.

Comment: Esse template utiliza fullPage.js que pode obter aqui: https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/

Comment: Obrigado pessoal com a resposta de vocês já me esclareceu muito! @PauloRamos era disso que estava precisando valeu cara

Answer (score 0):

Esse template utiliza a library opensource **fullPage.JS** (https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) através da qual é gerida a transição de ecrãs, menus, etc., com alguma customização adicional nas transições CSS.

O **efeito parallax** utiliza uma extensão adicional: https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/extensions/parallax.html

Consulte também o projeto no **GitHub**: https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullpage.js/